# iOS - Category method not getting called when testing of device

Tags: ios, nsdate, categories

I have this category:

```
@interface NSDate (PrettyDate)
- (NSString *)prettyDate;
@end



#import "NSDate+PrettyDate.h"

@implementation NSDate (PrettyDate)

- (NSString *)prettyDate
{
  NSString *prettyTimestamp = nil;

  float delta = [self timeIntervalSinceNow] * -1;

  if (delta < 60) {
    prettyTimestamp = @"Just now";
  } else if (delta < 120) {
    prettyTimestamp = @"One minute ago";
  } else if (delta < 3600) {
    prettyTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes ago", (int) floor(delta/60.0) ];
  } else if (delta < 7200) {
    prettyTimestamp = @"One hour ago";      
  } else if (delta < 86400) {
    prettyTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hours ago", (int) floor(delta/3600.0) ];
  } else if (delta < ( 86400 * 2 ) ) {
    prettyTimestamp = @"One day ago";       
  } else if (delta < ( 86400 * 7 ) ) {
    prettyTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d days ago", (int) floor(delta/86400.0) ];
  } else {
    NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    prettyTimestamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"On %@", [formatter stringFromDate:self]];
  }

  return prettyTimestamp;
}

@end
```

And I'm calling it like so:

```
NSDateFormatter *currentFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
currentFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
NSDate *date = [currentFormat dateFromString:dateString];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [date prettyDate];
```

It works fine on the simulator, but on the device the category method isn't even called, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's just an error in you copy and paste, but you're missing your implementation. Have you tried running a clean build? Also, how are you referencing the category method's file?

Comment: It's an error in the copy/paste let me fix it. And yeah, clean build and all fails on device, works on simulator.

Comment: Try logging respondsToSelector on the device and see what it says.

Comment: What value does `date` have? What about `dateString`?

Comment: date string is a date in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss date comes out nil on the device.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a symbolic breakpoint in the debugger, does it get resolved?  Does execution stop at it if so?

Are you compiling this code into a static .a library?  The GCC linker requires use of the -all_load flag to ensure categories in static libraries get picked up.

Comment: No, it doesn't stop at the breakpoint. What do you mean compiling into a .a library? Care to explain?

Comment: If you're building this into a static library, you need to either include -all_load or the macro category inclusion hack. However, I think that's the same for simulator vs. device.

Comment: You're gonna need to be more explicit, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sometimes you have code which needs to be shared between multiple apps. One way of achieving this is to compile the shared code to a static library (file extension .a) which can then be linked against in your apps.

The first thing I normally check when something works in the Simulator but not on the device is file name case sensitivity - the Simulator is case insensitive but the device is case sensitive. I can't think how that could apply here, but throwing it out just in case it sparks an idea for someone else.

Comment: Is that really necessary for a simple category?

Comment: WEnt to the build settings and under Other Linker Flags I set the -all_load for both Debug and Release. Still doesn't work on device.